# WPF menu - Intermediate menu item clickable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, menu, menuitem

I have a menu in wpf(mvvm). Menu is of three level.

```
         Level1
```

Level2_1                                Level2_2

Level2_1_1, Level2_1_2, Level2_1_3

How do I make intermediate menu item clickable. I mean, I want to make "Level2_1" clickable.

Example:-

```
             America

California              Kenucky         Indiana

              Louisville  Lexington
```

I want to make submenu(California, Kenucky,Indiana) clickable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you currently have? I have some idea of what you might be asking, but it would be guessing.

Comment: I cant paste code here. But what i need is... I have a wpf menu , which I am populating from an xml file. I have different levels in this menu. I mean lets take parent menu as "US"...and it contains submenu as "california, kentucky, indiana". Under "kentucky" submenu, i have another two submenu as "louisville","lexington". If I need to make submenu "Kentucky" as clickable.

Answer (score 1):

**That's not how menus work.**

Menus are either a clickable option, or a parent menu of a submenu.  Doing otherwise is going to, at best, confuse your users.  Also, you are looking at a maintenance headache.  I can think of no other application that does this.

There may be a "hack" to do this, but I would recommend against it.

A better option is to have a filterable UI (be it a View, or a dialog, or whatever) that allows your users to chose which option(s) or filters to use.  It will be much more logical and therefore easier to use, and it will be much more easy to code and maintain.